# Unable to connect to my vsftp server via "INTERNET"

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I set up a simple vsftp server on Ubuntu Desktop 18.04. On LAN, it works fine. I wanna connect to my server outside my LAN. How can I?

-
I tried using ftp://publicip
Doesn't work.

My aim is to serve files from my Desktop to anyone in the world with any device which has a web browser.

Comment: Did you port-forward traffic through your router to the proper machine for the FTP ports?

Comment: Forwarded 20-21 to my machine. No luck.

Comment: Are you using passive or active FTP mode?

Comment: I didn't configure this because I don't really know the difference. I mean I didn't set pasv parameter. So, active mode maybe?

Comment: Tried with these parameters as well, no luck \n pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=41361
pasv_max_port=65534
pasv_address=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Comment: well you have to port forward THOSE ports too...

Comment: I did forward those ports too.